# UrlReferrer is null after clicking hyperlink control

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, hyperlink

I've got my asp:hyperlink control on a page named "Items"

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="btnAddToCart" Text="Add To Cart" runat="server" Visible="False" />
```

The codebehind is setting the NavigateUrl for the hyperlink control.

```
Dim btnAddToCart As HyperLink = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnAddToCart"), HyperLink)
btnAddToCart.NavigateUrl = "http://fake.com/checkout?productid=123"
```

When I click the button, the "Checkout" page loads.  However, when I check the Request object in my .NET code, the Request.UrlReferrer is empty... and none of the other properties provide detail that the previous page was "Items".

Is my mistake horribly obvious, or is there some other way I should be redirecting so that the UrlReferrer gets populated?

Comment: What do you mean by **page "Items"**? Besides, **UrlReferrer** is not reliable. Currently, there is not enough information to troubleshoot the issue; please post the code.

Comment: @Win "Items" is the name of my page... call it "A" if you like. 
Should I be using some other method to check referrer?
I posted the code I thought was relevant, I don't think you want all 3,000 lines posted.  What information are you missing and I'll gladly add it.

Comment: Ideally, you want to make a very small replicable code so that we can simulate the issue. While creating the small code, you might end up finding the solution by yourself.

Comment: @Win fair enough :-P